# I want to read in lines from a file input and print out the number of digits on a line

Tags: java, file, printing

I have this block of code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Problem
{
   public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
   {
      Scanner file = new Scanner( new File( "file.dat" ) );
      int times = file.nextInt();      
      file.nextLine();
      for( int zz = 0; zz < times; zz++ )
      {
           ???
      }
   }
}
```

The goal is to read in lines from file.dat (pre-provided), and then output the number of digits on a line that was read in. However, whenever I put `int[] array = {file.nextLine};` in the space under the for loop, it doesn't run. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `file.nextLine()` returns a string as output parameter. Please see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29

Comment: Do you have a pre-defined format of the file.dat on how the numbers are stored?

Comment: Can you post a few lines from your input file and the expected count for those lines?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `BufferedReader` instead:

```
file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.dat"));

 while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
   System.out.println(line.split("\\s+").length);
            }
```

`split()` returns a `String[]` and you just use its array length